# Where's The Best Place to use Register_Shutdown_Function()?

Tags: debug

I want to use [Register Shutdown Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to track Fatal Errors, my question is, where's the best place to call this so it hits both WordPress, Plugin, and Theme Fatal Errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress core register a shutdown function on its own ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/654e46f03d3806b80a691e8a21100ee6c5d8873a/wp-settings.php#L99)) the function `shutdown_action_hook` registered to be ran on shutdown, call

```
do_action( 'shutdown' );
```

and little more ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/18a62537472eb3d1185583449bc53a81761dda31/wp-includes/load.php#L602)).

So, if you want to register a shutdown function in *WordPress way* just add your function on 'shutdown' hook:

```
add_action( 'shutdown', 'my_shutdown_callback' );

function my_shutdown_callback() {
  error_log('Goodbye');
}
```

Where to put this code is not very important, a plugin, a mu plugin, functions.php, it doesn't matter, it will run always on shutdown...

Of course register it as soon as possible allows you to catch early errors, so using a [mu plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) you can catch errors that happen on plugins init.

Comment: I mean, are there really any other alternatives to putting it at the top of my themes `functions.php` file so that it registers as early as possible? +1

Comment: @Howdy_McGee when developing a theme, no, there is no (useful) alternative. Possible alternatives are are on top of plugins or MU plugins files, but if you are developing a theme...

Comment: The reason that I'm looking to do this is because I do manage multiple themes, and would like to run automatic updates on all of them but the problem with that is if one of the plugins isn't compatible and throws a fit. The only other option I was thinking is to manually add it to wp-config.php or a similar file but I'm not sure what files get overwritten on update.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee use a plugin, or a mu plugin. In the latter case you can just put the code I posted (of course using the real callback) and save the file in the mu-plugins folder and you are done. If you use a regular plugin than you have to use plugin headers and activate it in backend.